# PHP in HTML: Incorrect echo response

Tags: php, html

I am new to web development and am learning to use PHP inside HTML.

An HTML I made looks like

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
  </body>
 </html>
```

This, I expect to produce on web-page

```
Hello World
```

However it is producing the following:

```
Hello World'; ?>
```

Why is the

```
'; ?>
```

coming?

Thanks.

Comment: Save it as .php not .html.

Comment: Because PHP is not enabled? (hint: browser view source)

Answer (score 5):

You need to have PHP enabled. Either...

1) You don't have PHP enabled on the web server

2) The extension isn't .php, it's .html (and isn't parsed as such)

Comment: Or, they're not using a web server at all and just viewing a static HTML file off their filesystem.

Comment: That's a fair possibility.

Comment: Yeah, I am viewing a static HTML file off my system, and it is in .html extension

Comment: That's not going to work, you'll need to install a web server stack, like WAMP - http://www.wampserver.com/en/ (If you're on Windows), and then view the file from `localhost`, and it needs to be a `.php` file.